# Calling a javascript function with a parameter retrieved from the model in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, parameters

I have a JavaScript function that I need to call inside my body tags. My JavaScript function looks like this:

```
function NewExistingPicture(pictureName) {

    //code for JavaScript function
}
```

And this is what I'm trying to do in HTML:

```
Existing Photos:
<% foreach (var Photo in Model.ProductThumbnails) 
   { %>
      NewExistingPicture(<%= Html.Encode(Photo.PhotoName) %>) 
<% } %>
```

Obviously this isn't going to work, but I am at a loss as to how to pass the function the information from the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<% foreach (var Photo in Model.ProductThumbnails) 
   { %>
      NewExistingPicture('<%= Photo.PhotoName.Replace(@"'", @"\'") %>'); 
<% } %>
</script>
```

(the .Replace() is to escape any single quotes in your string, so the string you're creating will be valid)

Comment: Assuming users have any control at all over photo names, this is not safe (XSS).

Comment: Where's the XSS vulnerability? The .Replace guarantees that the entire photo name will be within the JS string, even evil input like "');alert('hacked');alert('".

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to do something like writting out a complete script section with all the javascript in it which is then run when the document has completed loading.

I think this might also be best written out from the controller code so you can set a variable and then insert that into the page.

```
<%= Model.Javascript %>
```

and in the controller;

```
ActionResult MyAction()
{
  myModel.Javascript = "<script>alert(9);</script";
  return View(myModel);
}
```

The above is completely untested but should work anyway me thinks.

Comment: You would need to create a Javascript property on the Model. For the sake of example, you may be better off using ViewData.

Comment: Agreed but I'm just not a big fan of ViewData.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>
<% var js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); %>
...
NewExistingPicture(<%= Html.Encode(js.Serialize(Photo.PhotoName)) %>)
```